# Tools for generating reports in PHP?

Tags: php

Somebody knows a tool or framework that able me to generate the same report in HTML, PDF and Excel with the same effort?

I know about PHPExcel or FPDF, but I don't wanna write and mantain many outputs. I want to have just one effort and have many outputs.

Thanks,

Armando

Answer (score 2):

You have to define a common representation for all your outputs.
For example, you can take HTML and then find tools like [`DOMpdf`](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/) that convert it in PDF.

You can also open HTML documents with MS Excel. Depending on your styles, it could break up your document though.

Comment: It's a solution that works but I'm looking for a tool that already makes a thing like this.